# How to save index of element within ng-repat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page where I want to show multiple banners that I created.

Each banner has multiple slides and there is a next and a prev button which toggles through these slides. I make every of banners by a button named `create banner`. It works with `ng-repeat`.

The problem is when I click on a next button in one of those banners to go to next slide of that banner, all of the banners change and go to next slide.

I know the problem is that the `$index` changes by clicking and affects all of the banners but I am confused how to handle.

I'll be really appreciated for your help. Here is the code :

```js
function nextSlide(index, slide, $scope) {
  for (var counter = 0; counter < $scope.ReceivedJsonFile.length; counter++) {
    for (var t = 0; t <= index; t++) {
      if (t == index) {
        if ($scope.ReceivedJsonFile[t].Type == "Banner") {
          for (var m = 0; m <= slide; m++) {
            if (m == slide) {
              $scope.selectedSlide += 1
              if ($scope.selectedSlide > $scope.ReceivedJsonFile[t].Children.length - 1) {
                $scope.selectedSlide = 0;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

```
<div cng-repeat="item in ReceivedJsonFile">
    <img ng-click="nextSlide($index,selectedSlide)" src="BContent/Images/Icons/arrow-88-16.png" style="position:relative;right:0;top:50%;-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);transform: rotate(180deg);" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: $scope.selectedSlide is initialized to 0 for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to give more precise advice w/o HTML code, but the problem is clear: you have a single scope variable selectedSlide, which is shared between all the banners.

You have at least 2 options:

- use an array of "selectedSlide" indexed by banner number

  ```
  $scope.selectedSlide = [];

  function nextSlide(index, slide, $scope) {
      for (var counter = 0; counter < $scope.ReceivedJsonFile.length; counter++) {
      for (var t = 0; t <= index; t++) {
      if (t == index) {
          if ($scope.ReceivedJsonFile[t].Type == "Banner") {
              for (var m = 0; m <= slide; m++) {
                  if (m == slide) {
                      $scope.selectedSlide[index] += 1
                                                     if ($scope.selectedSlide[index] > $scope.ReceivedJsonFile[t].Children.length - 1) {
                          $scope.selectedSlide[index] = 0;
                      }

                  }
              }
          }
      }
  ```

  ofc, with this approach you have to modify your html to use selectedSlide[index] in ng-repeat, where applicable
- alternatively, you can create a directive for a banner which is perhaps a more proper angularjs approach. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive for reference.

Comment: really thank you for your help  , i send my html code here

Comment: <div cng-repeat="item in ReceivedJsonFile">
.
.
.
.
.

<img ng-click="nextSlide($index,selectedSlide)" src="BContent/Images/Icons/arrow-88-16.png" style="position:relative;right:0;top:50%;-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);transform: rotate(180deg);" />
</div>